# Google Play services location APIs force GPS

Tags: android, gps, location

My application require GPS accuracy.

I am using the new fuse location API.

It seems that if another application is using the GPS, then I get location updates with GPS accuracy, otherwise the location update has network accuracy.

Is there a way to force the fuse location service to activate the GPS or do I need to use the old LocationManager API?

Here is the relevant part of the code I use to create the API client and request location updates:

```
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
googleApiClient.connect();
```

In the onConnected method I have this:

```
locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
locationRequest.setInterval(1000 * 60);
locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000 * 30);
locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
```

Comment: "Is there a way to force the fuse location service to activate the GPS" -- AFAIK, no. You can request `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY`, as you appear to be doing. However, it is up to the developers of the Play Services location stuff to determine how to handle that.

Comment: So it is best to use the LocationManager in that case right?

Comment: if you still have the problem could you tell me what is the permission you are using for location in the manifest file?

Comment: @A.Edwar
I am using  android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, but I change to use LocationManager to solve the problem. So I do not know if it is solved or not with the fuse location.